# Give back button to bootstrap steps

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-steps

I am using this steps plugin/code on my site:
https://bootsnipp.com/fullscreen/RlOe3

What i want, is that when i am on the second or third tab, i want to show a back button to the previous div/step.

If i add the button with `class="backBtn"`, how can i go back with the javascript?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you have a working example. I used the code from the link you provided. What I did was the following:

- added two back buttons => `<button class="btn btn-primary backBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button" >Back</button>`
- looked how the `next` function is implemented and reverse the behavior

I also disable the next step when you press back, as it should be. If you also want to clear the values, in can be easily done, but that's your homework.

Cheers!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
          allBackBtn = $('.backBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });
  
  allBackBtn.click(function() {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content");
    var curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id");
    
    var currStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().children("a");
    var prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");
    
    prevStepWizard.trigger('click');
    currStepWizard.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:40px;
}
.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}
.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
  
<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Step 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 1</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input  maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address" ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 2</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary backBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button" >Back</button>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 3</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-primary backBtn btn-lg pull-left" type="button" >Back</button>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
</div>
```